# changes to transfer file from android to a php server

Tags: android

Hi I wrote a code to transfer json object from android phone to php server as shown below. Can you please suggest me the changes required in my code if I want to transfer a file to the server.

```
private String constructDataRecord(JSONObject data, String type)
{
    JSONObject dataRecord = new JSONObject();
    try
        {
            dataRecord.put("date", timeStr);
            dataRecord.put("time_stamp", c.getTimeInMillis());
            dataRecord.put("user", IMEI);
            dataRecord.put("type", type);
            dataRecord.put("ver", VER);
            dataRecord.put("data", data);
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception", e);
        }

        String url = "http://mpss.csce.uark.edu/~smandava/index.php";
        Map<String, String> kvPairs = new HashMap<String, String>();
        kvPairs.put("data", dataRecord.toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "Exception");
        HttpResponse re = null;


        try {
            re = doPost(url, kvPairs);
            String  temp  = EntityUtils.toString(re.getEntity());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


      //  if (temp.compareTo("SUCCESS")==0)
        {
     //       Toast.makeText(this, "Sending complete!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return dataRecord.toString();
    }


   public static HttpResponse doPost(String url, Map<String, String> kvPairs) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException 
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        if (kvPairs != null && kvPairs.isEmpty() == false) 
        {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(kvPairs.size());
            String k, v;
            Iterator<String> itKeys = kvPairs.keySet().iterator();
            while (itKeys.hasNext()) 
            {
                k = itKeys.next();
                v = kvPairs.get(k);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(k, v));
            }             
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        }
        HttpResponse response;
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example of this [here](http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/).